# Apache .htaccess folder redirect rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to know how to create the folowing rules in the same .htaccess file:

1. redirect from `example.com/st` to `example.com`
2. redirect from `example.com/[ANY STRING]` to `new-example.com/[ANY STRING]`

The problem is that I need to send the query string as is.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but you can try this code in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# your first requirement
RewriteRule ^st/?$ / [L]

# your second requirement; it will also append existing query string
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://new-example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```